# error run time 1004 vba when I changed the excel version to excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help. In our company we have an issue with an excel file since we have change the excel version and dowload excel 2016 we have the error 1004.

In other computers it works good.

```
Private Sub SauvValid()
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
' SAUVEGARDE DANS LE REPERTOIRE SPECIAL DE SAUVEGARDE
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------

' sauvegarde du fichier dans l'emplacement de sauvegarde mensuelle
    nomFichier = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 18)
    repertoireSauv = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    repertoire = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "yyyy") & "\" & _
            Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "mm") & "-" & Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "mmmm") & "\"
    Call GESTION_DROITS.Masquage
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=repertoire & nomFichier & "SvEnvoiValid-" & _
        Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmm") & ".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

' sauvegarde du fichier de façon normale incrementale
    nomFichier = nomFichier & Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmm") & ".xlsm"
    ChDir repertoireSauv
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=repertoireSauv & nomFichier, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call GESTION_DROITS.Affichage

End Sub
```

Any help please.[image]

Comment: Click Debug and then check what the path and filename is that you're attempting to write to. Also, make sure the document isn't shared before SaveAs-ing.

Comment: When I click on debug this part became yellow : ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=repertoire & nomFichier & "SvEnvoiValid-" & _
        Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmm") & ".xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
which means that the issue is linked to this part !

Comment: Perfect. If you then enter into the 'immediate window' the following: `debug.print repertoire & nomFichier & "SvEnvoiValid-" & Format(Sheets("Calcul Indexe").Range("B1").Value, "yyyymmdd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmm") & ".xlsm"` and hit enter it will tell you the full path/filename that it's trying to save.

Comment: Thank you for your help it gave me this result
P:\2018\10-octobre\Copie de Sv-Indexe Modifie-SvEnvoiValid-20181025-1230.xlsm

Comment: So if you copy that result and attempt to manually save the file using that *exact* path, do you get an error?

Comment: it helps a lot many thanks